# Different request code

Tags: android

hey i got strange issue

i start activity from fragment

```
public static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 101;
(...)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

and in host activity i get other requestCode

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Utils.PrintDebug("CurrentFragment: "+currentFragment+" requestCode "+requestCode);
}
```

in logcat i get this

> CurrentFragment: CreateNoteFragment requestCode 196710

i dont have any idea what is happen and what for i should search

Comment: what is ur issue?????

Comment: Is CreateNoteFragment correct? Or should that be something different too?

Comment: dont you have to override super(requestcode,resultcode,data)?? if you have come from fragment also starting activity from the fragment itself is discouraged and you should implement an interface to do so

Comment: @Illegal Argumen idk if i good understand u but i change fragment as in solution and voila its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** by changin way to call `startActivityForResult` in fragment

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

now its work as it should